# how to change a static testimonials into dynamic

Tags: plugins, customization, theme-development, css, screen-layout

i have a section in my home page where i have testimonials and i want to customize it !
im using TC Testimonials plugin and i want the dots to be separated and in front of the testimonial section

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fx0qhc09ldvfvhf/AABrQu-Cu1GjxI8HhLAmmRWha?dl=0

i can give you html/css based on dev tools

Comment: Most of that should just be controlled by CSS. If you find yourself struggling with plugin's CSS, you could just write these as HTML widgets and write the HTML to make it easier to style them the way you like.  Question:  How are they dynamic?

Comment: dynamic like when you click on the dot in the right side or the left the slide goes in that direction i meant with adujsting proprties like timing to slide automaticaly